# implementing a 50ns delay in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, spi, xilinx-ise

I'm sending data to and A/D converter and I need the command data to be delayed at least 50ns from clk_19khz. Here is what I have so far. 
How do I insert a delay of 50ns which is a requirement for the A/D between the clk_19khz and my first Dout bit to the A/D? 
I'm using a Xilinx FPGA. Thanks for the help!

```
         library IEEE;
        use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

         -- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
         -- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
         --use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

         -- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
         -- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
         --library UNISIM;
         --use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

      entity PSOL is
        Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
               clk_19khz : OUT std_logic;
               Dout :out std_logic);
        end PSOL;

     architecture Behavioral of PSOL is
         signal temp : std_logic;
         signal count : integer range 0 to 1301 := 0; --1301
         signal temp2 : std_logic;
         signal dcount : integer range 0 to 11 := 0; --
         signal start : std_logic  := '1'; -- indicates the start of                      
         signal parity : std_logic := '1'; --used to varify data sent
         signal stop : std_logic := '0'; --indicate when word/command has                             
       --signal chip_select : bit :='1'; -- active low



     begin
       process (clk)
         begin
            if (clk' EVENT AND clk='1') then
                if (count = 1301) then --1301
                    temp <= not(temp);
                    count <=0;
                else
                    count <= count + 1;     
                end if;
            end if;
     end process;

        clk_19khz <= temp;
         temp2 <= temp;


      process (temp2)
        begin
            If (temp2' EVENT and temp2 ='0') then

                dcount <= dcount + 1;
                parity <= '1';
                stop <= '0';
                start <='1';
            if (dcount < 12 and start = '1' and stop = '0') then
                CASE dcount is
                  when 1 => Dout <= start; -- need delay 50ns before this 
                  when 2 => Dout <= '0';
                  when 3 => Dout <= '1';
                  when 4 => Dout <= '0';
                  when 5 => Dout <= '1';
                  when 6 => Dout <= '0';
                  when 7 => Dout <= '0';
                  when 8 => Dout <= '1';
                  when 9 => Dout <= '1';
                  when 10 => Dout <= parity;
                  when 11 => Dout <= '0';
                  when others => null;
                 end case;
            end if;
        end if;             
        --dcount <= 0;
        --start <='1';

    end process;



 end Behavioral;
```

Comment: So what's the clock rate of `clk`, and is it related to `clk_19khz` by an integer ratio?

Comment: clk is a 50MHz clock clk_19khz is the clock i generated from the 50MHz clock that I need to clock in the data to the A/D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clock (50 MHz) has a period of `20 ns`. So you'll need a modulo-3 counter to count a delay of at least 3 clock pulses which gives a delay of `60 ns`.

Declarations:

```
signal delay_en : std_logic;
signal delay_us : unsigned(1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal delay_ov : std_logic;
```

Usage:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if (delay_en = '1') then
      delay_us <= delay_us + 1;
    else
      delay_us <= (others => '0');
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
delay_ov <= '1' when (delay_us = 2) else '0';
```

Your current implementation needs to drive `delay_en` while it's waiting for the timespan. If the delay is over, it emits the signal `delay_ov` (ov = overflow). This can be used by your solution to go on the in algorithm. Your code should also deassert `delay_en`, what clears the counter to 0.

Comment: where are you changing delay_en?

Comment: @hfbroady Simplified the counter and added usage text.

Comment: thanks for the help. I was also told that the design is a bad one because of the why i'm using clk_19khz. Any thoughts?

Comment: `clk_19khz`/`temp` is a self created clock. It can be used for output pins but it shouldn't be used for processes as a new clock (what you are doing by using `temp2'event`). So your circuit is not fully synchronous to clk (the main clock). The solution and *clean* way is to use `clk` for all your processes and `temp` as an clock enable signal.